# Prevent custom repository from overriding distribution package Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I have a custom repo in my sources to provide smartgit:

```
ppa:eugenesan/ppa
```

For the last week I havent been able to get past the login loop trying everything under the sun. Today I found that this repo updated these 4 packages to a custom version (based on GNOME 3.12):

- ubuntu-session
- gnome-session-common
- gnome-session-bin
- gnome-session

This was not desired and has since been fixed. I would like to keep this repo for smartgit but not have it override anything else. Is this possible?